# Regex expression matching block of lines

Tags: regex

I have this kind of file:

```
Analysis of its root cause:
Blablablablabla
blabablabkjhjk
kjbsqbdqbds

Details of the fix
blablabla

Analysis of its root cause:
fddsfsdfsdfdsfs
blnskdbbqbbb
xxxxggggggg

Details of the fix
blablabla
```

Analysis of its root cause is repeated x times in the file. I would like to get the block of text delimited by "Analysis of its root cause" and "Details of the fix".

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I tried to edit my post to say Hello but it does not work, so Hello :)

Comment: What is your regex flavor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there is some better way to do this, but that's what I could manage:

```
/(?(?<=Analysis of its root cause:\n)((.*\n)*)(?=Details of the fix\n))/gU
```

I'm using positive lookahead and lookbehind, and the following modifiers:

`g` - `global` - Don't return after first match

`u` - `Ungreedy` - Make quantifiers lazy

Try it online: https://regex101.com/r/xpz7pg/2

Answer (score 1):

Not a regex answer, but using perl

Put your lines into a single file.

```
 perl -e '$/="Analysis of its root cause:"; #Sets the record delimiter 

      while(<>){ #Iterates over the file, record by record

      chomp; #Removes the delimiter

      if ($_ =~ /\n(.*?)\nDetails of the fix\n(.*)\n/s){ #Matches strings between Details of the fix. . is allowed to match newline

      print "ONE:$1TWO:$2"} # $1 is the analysis, $2 is the details
      }'
      file.txt
```

Output

```
ONE:Blablablablabla
blabablabkjhjk
kjbsqbdqbds
TWO:blablabla
ONE:fddsfsdfsdfdsfs
blnskdbbqbbb
xxxxggggggg
TWO:blablabla
```